# Can't ping from Win7 running on an MacBook Pro and Can't ping MacBook Pro from any other PC

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, macbook-pro

I have Windows 7 Enterprise running on MacBook Pro and for some reason I'm not able to ping any PC in the house from it and the other way around meaning I can't ping the MacBook Pro running Win7 from any other PC.

I looked online but I can't find anything that explains this issue or how to resolve it. Any help will be really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Are you dual booting on the MacBook Pro, or are you running Windows 7 within a VM?

Comment: Dual booting!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite likely inbound ICMP ping requests are being blocked either by default by the [Windows 7 firewall](http://www.sysprobs.com/enable-ping-reply-windows-7) or by an antivirus program like [McAfee](https://community.mcafee.com/thread/29439) you're using.

Comment: thank you, it was being blocked by the Firewall. Question, in this case I disabled the entire firewall. Is there a rule I could modify so I don't have to disable the firewall??

Comment: Sure.  On that Win7 firewall page I cited, there's a link to another page (http://www.sysprobs.com/enable-ping-in-vista) giving instructions on creating a rule to allow ping without disabling the firewall completely.  The instructions are for Vista but Win7 is basically the same.